# Sql subquery problem

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a table with products. One column contains the expiry date of these products.
If they don't have such an expiry date it is written '-' .
I want to get the id's of the products which are expired and i have the following problem:

**The statement**:

```
SELECT id from product where 
(select expiry from product where expiry not in ('-')) < GETDATE()
```

**The error**:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery 
follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

How can I get the products that meet the condition written above?

Comment: What is the data type of the field expiry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compare one value to many in that way. I suspect what you really want is:

```
SELECT id 
FROM product 
WHERE expiry < GETDATE()
    AND expiry <> '-'
```